# How to deduplicate & get the first occurence of row?

Tags: ssis

My dataflow has the following 2 columns:

```
PK  time
-----------------
2   03:40:01
2   08:21:59
4   08:21:59
4   10:03:12
4   11:20:12
4   12:45:04
```

Now I want to deduplicate the rows, using the PK column and I need the **first occurence** for each PK (using the previously sorted time column). So in this case, I need:

```
PK  time
-----------------
2   03:40:01
4   08:21:59
```

How can I achieve this without writing to external staging/intermediate tables? I need something that gives me the row with `MIN(time)` with the unique PK.

When I use Sort Transformation with PK column, using sort type **descending**  it gives me only the first occurence of the first PK row. For all subsequent PK rows in my output, the value of time column is random.

Comment: Use Aggregate element and you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog post](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.ca/2009/01/eliminating-duplicate-primary-keys-in.html) by Todd McDermid on how to achieve de duplication without writing to external table. One of the 3 scenarios should help you.
On a side note, why dont you want to get this done on the table side. Its faster and more easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Script Component Example for redirecting [duplicates](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/12/redirect-duplicate-rows.html). And if your source is a database table you could also try something with [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).